# ApplicationError: Solver (gurobi) did not exit normally

Tags: pyomo, gurobi

I'm using  gurobi academic license and i've followed every steps to activate the license but i get the following error whenever i call the gurobi solver on model which i wrote in pyomo :

```
ERROR: Solver (gurobi) returned non-zero return code (1)
ERROR: Solver log: Restricted license - for non-production use only - expires
    2023-10-25 Read LP format model from file /tmp/tmp6ssbilg6.pyomo.lp
    Reading time = 0.02 seconds x2773: 2775 rows, 2773 columns, 19387 nonzeros
    Gurobi Optimizer version 9.5.1 build v9.5.1rc2 (linux64) Thread count: 2
    physical cores, 4 logical processors, using up to 4 threads Traceback
    (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module> File
      "/home/ali_p/anaconda3/envs/py37_64/lib/python3.7/site-
      packages/pyomo/solvers/plugins/solvers/GUROBI_RUN.py", line 114, in
      gurobi_run
        model.optimize()
      File "src/gurobipy/model.pxi", line 864, in gurobipy.Model.optimize
    gurobipy.GurobiError: Model too large for size-limited license; visit
    https://www.gurobi.com/free-trial for a full license
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the error message, the license key was not found. Make sure to read the section of the Quick Start Guide called Retrieving and Setting Up a Gurobi License ([Linux](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/quickstart_linux/retrieving_and_setting_up_.htm), [Windows](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/quickstart_windows/retrieving_and_setting_up_.html), [Mac](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/quickstart_mac/retrieving_and_setting_up_.html)).